# Segfault error from printf?

Tags: arrays, assembly, sparc

I'm doing SPARC assembly.
Here's some of my code:

```
convert:
    save    %sp, -96, %sp

    mov     %i0, %l0       !%i0 has a long array
    mov     %i1, %l1       !%i1 has a char array


process:
    ld      [%i0], %o0      !maps firstArray[0] to %l0
    mov     10, %o1         !maps 10 to %o1 
    call    .div            !divide by 10 to get 10s place
    nop

    mov     %o0, %l3        !stores result in l3
    stb     %l3, [%i1]      !stores result in the second array


    mov     %l3, %o1        !checking contents after calculation
    call    printf
    nop
```

printf causes an error, and I'm not sure why. I tried this with several of the local registers. I need it to check my results. What should I do?

Also I'm not actually sure if my way of implementing the parameter arrays is correct, but I wasn't getting this error before I added the printf statement.

Comment: I think I figured it out - %o0 needs to be set with a format string.

Comment: You should post that as an answer.  That is, indeed, the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:
%o0 needs to be set with a format string.